# How many currents are there in a circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

I've been studying circuits lately and I have a difficulty when applying *Kirchhoff's rules*. My question has to do with how can I find how many currents are in a circuit. I know about junctions etc and how it splits. But for example, when you have 2 or 3 batteries how many currents are there and which current runs through each resistor? I've been trying to practice online and I came across this circuit:

[image]

And I don't understand why there are 3 currents when there are 4 batteries. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Please, have a look at this site policy about homework-like questions. I think you could rewrite your question stressing more the general concepts and issues than the specific example. It would be better to omit the drawing, too specific.

Comment: WTF, current $I_2$ goes thought battery $E_3$ and $I_3$ through battery $E_2$. Way to go to confuse people.

Answer (score 4):

How many currents there are has nothing to do with how many batteries there are. Each *uninterrupted* part of the circuit will have its own amount of current going through it. If two batteries are in that same part, they will carry the same current ($E_3$ and $E_4$ in your case).

An uninterrupted part in this case means any stretch of circuit that does not have any way for current to leave (like a junction).

Instead of current, you can also think of it as a liquid going through pipes to make the intuition easier.

Answer (score 0):

In this type of circuit, the number of uniquely defined currents can be equal to the number of “holes” through the circuit. In this case there are two holes and $I_1$ can be expressed as ${I_2} + {I_3}$.  I like to work with current loops and voltage drops. In this case, if $I_1$ and $I_2$ each loop around their corresponding holes, then the current down through $R_3$ is ${I_1} – {I_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The by the book approach is to say there are 8 wire segments (between two nodes) each with its own current and voltage equation. So we start with **8** currents.

For example $V_{\rm bc} = -R_3 I_{\rm bc} $ or $V_{\rm ge} = E_2 - r_2 I_{\rm ge}$.

Now there is a reduction in variables that can happen for each node that connects two wires only. The current is shared between the connected wires, so $I_2 = I_{\rm bc}= I_{\rm cd}= I_{\rm de}$ for example. This leaves us with **3** currents.

But the circuit can be described by two loops, with some wires shard between the loops. These two loop currents $I_A$ and $I_B$ are used with the principal of superposition to describe the current on each wire.

[image: fig1]

For example $V_{\rm ge} = E_2 - r_2 (I_A-I_B)$

In this sense there are only **2** currents.